# Is DNS service secure?

Tags: dns

I am based outside of the US, but I still want to watch Netflix. So I am thinking about signing up a DNS service such as [unblocked-us](http://www.unblock-us.com/), but I worry that as I am now querying an unknown ( relative to Google DNS, that is) DNS server, my details over the internet may not be secured, as the DNS service provider, or hackers can hack into the DNS server and leak my browsing habits and my other private information.

What do you think? Do you think that my fear is warranted?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Why are you calling that DNS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)? It seems like a remote http proxy, is all... And the rest of the question also seems confused, I think you misunderstand most of the terms you used.

Comment: @AviD The asker is correct in this case, it is a DNS service not a proxy or VPN service. They handle the DNS requests and then resolve them in their own way.

Comment: @Gerve I'm not sure what you're saying. Are you disagreeing with Chris's answer below?

Comment: @AviD no I agree with Chris's answer, but I disagree with your comment. Unblock US operate a DNS server that allows clients to bypass geo IP restrictions from media providers. When their DNS server receives requests to Netflix they respond with their own proxy IPs. The asker was correct in describing the service as a DNS server.

Comment: @Gerve what you describe is really both - the DNS server to actively create a (MitM) proxy for the client, which is the core service. Just because they *use* DNS to hijack the connection, doesn't mean its not a proxy service.

Comment: @AviD I was only bothered because you told the asker he was confused, he wasn't confused and his question was worded correctly. The service is a DNS server, how the DNS is resolved is an aside.

Comment: Yeah, you're right - the OP was correct in calling it DNS server, even if the proxy server is still a part of the service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I understand, unblocked-us is setup by pointing your computer to their DNS server. Their DNS server answers ALL DNS requests with their own servers, thus becoming a proxy/MITM.

E.g. you want to goto Youtube.com. This would resolve to 173.194.112.104
in a regular DNS server. However going through Unblocked-us DNS server 
they would yield a different reply, their own IP address. This can be 
illustrated better with the nslookup command:

```
nslookup netflix.com 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS)
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8
Non-authorative answer: 
Name:    netflix.com
Address:  69.53.236.17

nslookup netflix.com 208.122.23.22 (Unblock-us)
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  208.122.23.22
Name:    netflix.com
Addresses:  173.208.170.14
      192.227.246.14
      204.12.200.14
      67.216.222.14
      172.245.210.14
```

This is absolutely dangerous. You are not only querying someone else's DNS server, you are actually proxying everything through their servers as well. Whether you want this or not is up for you to decide.

Comment: It should be noted that secure connections (SSL) will remain secure as long as you pay attention to the domains and certificates (which you should do anyway).

Comment: You give this provider about the same trust as you give your local ISP, e.g. both have nearly full control over your traffic and can manipulate what they want (except SSL, unless they get a CA certificate somehow).
If both are entitled to this level of trust you must decide for yourself.